# scanf or getchar 10000 times at a time then program stopped in c

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    int ch,i;
     for (i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
        putchar(ch);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

It's working if you put chars less than 1000 but if you put chars 10000 at a time then program is stopped. I may think it's because of stdin buffer.
How can I solve this?

Here is more specific source.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main() {
    int i,n;
    char *p, ch;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    p = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) *n);

    if (p == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
        putchar(ch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Abode source is sample. 
- put `n` (word count to read) then put long long strings. program is stopped or wait something to be done.

input example 
1.

> 2000
>   lsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdkalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalssdafsdfsdfdd

this one is not working.

but below on is working.
2.

> 1000
>   jsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdkalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalssdafsdfsdfddkdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalsdklsakdjldjsalkfjalssdafsdfsdfdd1

Comment: I'd like to know how you are putting 10000 chars at one time. Although you probably want i <= 10000.

Comment: On many systems, you can't input more than a fixed length — which might be as little as about 256 bytes — on a single line of terminal input before the terminal driver locks up and refuses to take more.  On your system, the number lies somewhere between 1,000 and 10,000.  You'll have to determine where it is (could be 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192 or one or two characters less than one of those).  Given your update, the limit is most plausibly 1024 bytes.

Comment: Try in some other shell or OS.

Comment: how about this 


#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int ch,i;
     do {
        i = scanf("%c", (char*)&ch);
        putchar(ch);
     } while (i != EOF);
     return 0;
}

Comment: Input example 1 is not working. That's same result.

Comment: what do you mean with `p = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) *n);`, you didn't do any thing with that later.

Comment: It means I tried everything to get 10000 characters at a time. I know i don't need to use malloc. What if you don't know number of characters input? just scanf until stdin meets null or EOF? I just used malloc to test source.

Comment: How are you getting the input into your program?

Comment: @TomasShu, what hardware and OS? Look closely at Jonathan's comment. You have a hardware or OS limitation problem. Not a C problem. Both character input (`getchar`, `getc`...) and line input (`fgets`, `getline`) can accept a nearly unlimited number of characters so long as the OS doesn't provide a limitation. (line input limited to max size of buffer). A normal read loop from `stdin` like `while((c = getchar ()) != EOF && c != '\n')` will routinely read millions/billions of characters without a hitch. So posting your hardware may help identify the specific limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop may have been like the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    scanf(" %c", &p[i]);
    putchar(p[i]);
}
```

you can also try to flush your `stdin` input buffer in your code as adding the following line properly:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

*Edit: Due to undefined behavior possibility on some systems, an alternative and more common approach may be implemented like the following:*

```
int ch;

while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {

      // ...
}
```

or you can change stream buffer size properly by calling *setvbuf* function below:

```
int setvbuf (FILE* stream, char* buffer, int mode, size_t size);
```

Comment: I have tried to use fflush(stdin); But result was same. Depends on systems, I think fflush is unsafe. thanks.

Comment: According to your code, you are passing wrong variable address to your scanf function after dynamic memory allocation. Try to switch ch to pointer 'p' as I wrote above. Yes, using fflush may cause undefined behaviour in some systems and not a safe method but I assumed you're working on a desktop PC running Windows. It will probably work for that configuration if you use it properly. Give it a try.

Comment: And a last minute idea, have you tried to flush your stdout? It may be possible that your stdout buffer is full and needs to be flushed. If you don't want to flush your buffers everytime, you can set your stream buffer size with "setvbuf" function.